# Git or any other tools, creating a release from multiple tags in different repos

Tags: node.js, git, github, jenkins, gitlab

I'm looking for a new way to cut releases for my project.  I currently handle multiple products in each of their own repos.  For an example:

```
//parent repo
   //child repo1(tag1.1)
   //child repo2(tag2.4)
   //child repo3(tag6.4)
```

When it's time to cut a release, I go through each child repo and make sure that it's specific tag has passed it's testing phase.  If it hasn't, I roll back to the last passed branch.  This seams to get tedious doing this 60+ times and I'm looking for a better way.  I have looked into different tools and don't really know what way to go.

Tools I have looked at:

- GitHub
- GitLab
- NPM
- Jenkins
- And others

I have not ruled out any of these, but I am wondering what is the best option.

Has anyone had similar experience and what rout would be best for me?  Any tips you can give would be helpful? Any helpful references or tutorials would be perfect! I am open to any tools, or package management system.

Comment: can you elaborate on why you found out that NPM would not work? My first thought for this was to use a package management system as a solution. My experience is with NuGet - but NPM probably has similar options. I was going to suggest using "Pre-Release" packages for your child repo versions and have the parent use the latest possible version of the dependencies. If you need to test with a "Pre-Release" version, your build can explicitly allow these using the -IncludePreRelease option.

Comment: I didn't find that NPM would not work.  I am sure it would work.  I am just trying to find the best way of moving forward.  I have also updated the question to be more specific.